# Imagemagick text diacritics on image

Tags: imagemagick-convert

I'm trying to use ImageMagick to write some text on image. Unfortunatelly, by running this command

```
convert -background lightblue -fill blue -font /usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/Arial.ttf -pointsize 72 label:ĂăÂâÎîȘșȚț label.png
```

The resulting image has question marks instead of **ȘșȚț** characters, but ĂăÂâÎî are ok.

What am I missing? I'm on Ubuntu 14.04. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the problem was very simple, just that I wasn't aware of it. The fonts on my machine didn't have those characters.

I took the fonts from a windows machine and the output was ok.